# VScode makes WSL exit with error on any build task

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a build task in vscode that runs "make" in my default terminal, which I have set up as WSL. The problem is, no matter what command I make the task run, the terminal always exits instantly with the error `/bin/bash: - : invalid option`. I can't find any example elsewhere on the internet of this happening.

I've tried setting my line endings to \n, and various things from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6579) but nothing seems to work.

My task is

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "type": "shell",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "make",
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the same problem with vscode 1.31.1 (user setup) and the WSL shipped with Microsoft Windows 10.0.17134.619 (running Ubuntu 18.04).

When the default shell in vscode is configured to be WSL Bash, the following tasks.json file will fail with the error reported above:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build hello world",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g", "helloworld.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true,
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The above tasks.json file is the one suggested in the latest vscode documentation (see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) but does not really work. It looks like, for whatever reason, the final command issued by vscode to the terminal is ill-formed. This should look like "bash -c g++ ...". It would really help if this command could be echoed somewhere, so that the error would be evident.

The problem is solved if the default shell is configured to remain the Windows Command Prompt and the tasks.json file modified to take full control of the way the build terminal command is formed via the "options" field, as follows:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build hello world",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "",
            "args": [
                "g++", "-g", "helloworld.cpp"
            ],
            "problemMatcher":"$gcc",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true,
            },
            "options": {
                "shell": {
                    "executable": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System3\\bash.exe",
                    "args":["-c"]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The above, working tasks.json file makes use of options described in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks. Note that I have added the "problemMatcher" option. It has nothing to do with the issue described here, but it becomes handy for parsing the gcc output and locating errors in the source code.

So, in your case, you would need to:

1. Set the deafult vscode terminal to Command prompt
2. Add to your tasks.json file the option:

   ```
       "options": {
           "shell": {
               "executable": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System3\\bash.exe",
               "args":["-c"]
           }
   ```

In combination with your original tasks.json file, the above should result in a well-formed "make"command being issued in your WSL working folder.